# Highcharts upgrade to 8.1.2 not working with Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts, angular8

I am try to upgrade highcharts version from 6.2 to 8.1.2.

I am importing in following manner

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
declare var require: any;
require('highcharts/modules/annotations')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/highcharts-more')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/data')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/drilldown')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/exporting')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/funnel')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/heatmap')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/histogram-bellcurve')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/offline-exporting')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/parallel-coordinates')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/pareto')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/modules/boost')(Highcharts);
require('highcharts/themes/dark-blue')(Highcharts);

but when I am trying to overwrite the theme using
 Highcharts.theme = {
            colors:
                [
                    "#0082D1",
                    "#233E66",]}
```

it is not working
getting errors like
Property 'theme' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/xyz/Documents/gits/abc/node_modules/highcharts/highcharts")'.

I have switched back to lower version and then it works fine. Has anyone else run into this issue. It has been 2 days I am trying to solve this.

Comment: came across this sample with 7.1.2 https://github.com/heidi-luong1109/live/tree/f46d357a71e8b62fb6b177a8d7588f7b310f4754

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a problem with the TS declarations, luckily it can be easily fixed. You don't have to override the `Highcharts.themes` to apply a global theme. You could store the config in a regular variable and then just apply it with the `Highcharts.setOptions()` method.

```js
const theme = {
  colors: ["hotpink", "tomato"]
};

Highcharts.setOptions(theme);
```

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-7xd5rr

I have already reported the TS declaration issue on the Highcharts GitHub issue page, here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13794

Comment: Yes I reported it as well https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13793.. Thanks I will try this solution.

Comment: Great it worked. One note if you are trying to add legend related customization without using itemStyle it will not work, so I added itemStyle and it worked,  legend:{
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Roboto-light, sans-serif',
                    fontSize: '16px'
                },
                itemStyle: {
                    font: 'Roboto-light, sans-serif',
                    color: 'black'
                }
            },